# URL parse with javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

How to use javascript to get the following url - the value of id?

```
URL: http://www.url/id/2721/John
```

I would get the following values:

```
2721 and John
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what have you tried?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and why/where you're hung up. Don't just expect us to do the work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168260/how-to-parse-a-url 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840306/parse-url-with-javascript-or-jquery
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.match(re)`:

```
var r = "http://www.url/id/2721/John".match('\/id\/(\\d+)/([^/]+)');
```

The value `v[1]` will be `2721` and `r[2]` will be `John`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.split("/")` to separate the URL into pieces, then read the values.