# Regular Expression - Extract subdomain & domain

Tags: javascript, regex, url, subdomain

I'm trying to form a regular expression (javascript/node.js) which will extract the sub-domain & domain part from any given URL. This is what I ended up with:

```
[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)
```

Right now, I'm just considering http, https for protocol & exclude "www." portion from the subdomain+domain portion of an URL. I checked the expression & it almost works. But, here is the issue:

**Success**

```
'http://mplay.google.co.in/sadfask/asdkfals?dk=10'.match(/[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)/i)

'http://lplay.google.co.in/sadfask/asdkfals?dk=10'.match(/[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)/i)
```

**Failure**

```
'http://play.google.co.in/sadfask/asdkfals?dk=10'.match(/[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)/i)

'http://tplay.google.co.in/sadfask/asdkfals?dk=10'.match(/[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)/i)
```

I just use the first element from the result array. I'm not able to understand why "play." & "tplay." doesn't work. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Does "/p" and "/t" have any meaning for the regular expression evaluator?

Is there any other way of extracting sub-domain & domain from any given URL using a regular expression?

Edit -

Example:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skgames.trafficracer => **play.google.com**

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox => **mail.google.com**

Answer (score 102):

Your regex doesn't seem correct. Try this regex:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)/img
```

Domain name will be available in capture group #1.

**[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN6cZ7/365)**

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Match start
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?`: Match *optional* text `https://`
- `(?:[^@\n]+@)?`: Match *optional* text `:` followed by 1+ of any text and `@`
- `(?:www\.)?`: Match *optional* text `www.`
- `([^:\/\n?]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that are not (line break and `/` and `?` and `:`) and capture this value in capture group #1

Comment: what if I want only the domain name without the http(s) or www stuff?

Comment: That's what you get in captured group #1 in above regex. Check demo.

Answer (score 26):

You are about the one millionth person to try to parse URLs in JavaScript. I'm a little bit surprised you didn't see any of the existing questions on SO dating back years. The last thing you want to do is write yet another broken regexp, with all due respect to those that provided answers to your question.

There are many well documented libraries and approaches to handling this. Google it. The simplest way is to create an `a` element in memory, assign it an `href`, and then access its `hostname` and other properties. See http://tutorialzine.com/2013/07/quick-tip-parse-urls/. If that does not float your boat, then use a library like [uri.j](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)s.

If you really don't want to use a library, and insist on reinventing the wheel, then at least do something like the following:

```
function get_domain_from_url(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a').
    a.setAttribute('href', url);
    return a.hostname;
}
```

Essentially, you are delegating the extraction of the subdomain/domain part of the URL to the browser's URL parsing logic, which is MUCH better than anything you will ever write.

Also see [Parse URL with jquery/ javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript), [Parse URL with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript), [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript), or [parse URL with JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840306/parse-url-with-javascript-or-jquery). How did you miss those? Sorry, I have to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't need libraries. I'm aware of the libraries available for parsing URL. I need a regular expression. The scenario which I'm facing is, I can't go on write javascript code. The function takes regular expression, options and the value on which regex should be acted upon as arguments & returns the first match.

Comment: Great, good luck re-inventing the wheel and maintaining your broken regexps over the coming years. By the way, what do you mean by "can't go on write javascript code"?

Comment: I mean, I can't send the javascript code as argument. I need to pass regular expression

Comment: Then use this one: `var urlRegex = '^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?$';`

Comment: This code isn't used on the browser side. It is used in node.js. Yes, node.js has "url" module which can be used. But, unfortunately I can't use it because of the reason stated earlier. Your regex takes care of most of the URL types that we are going to encounter. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: For SO this answer is probably a little bit off-topic, but this lib saved my life! Thanks

Comment: Clever trick! Note there's an error in the code with a period at the end of the first line instead of a semicolon.

Answer (score 11):

The same RegExp as in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703406/460750), only added support for [protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL) like `//google.com`:

```
/^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)/im
```

[RegEx Demo](//regex101.com/r/MOIFTy/3)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution ignoring everything before `://`

```
.*\://?([^\/]+)
```

Incase you want to ignore `www.`

```
.*\://(?:www.)?([^\/]+)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. But, I also need to ignore the "www." part. How can I do that?

Comment: So, the final regular expression is **.*\:\/\/(?:www.)?([^\/]+)**

Comment: What purpose does the "?" after (?:www.) serve? I'm curious. Thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: have a look at this http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Answer (score 3):

Your regex expression works pretty well. You only need to remove the brackets. The final expression is:

```
^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript Regex using **Named Capturing Groups** breaks the link / URL up into its functional components:

```js
console.log("https://www.sub.domain.google.com:443/maps/place/Arc+De+Triomphe/@48.8737917,2.2928388,17z?query=1&foo#hash".match(/^(?<protocol>https?:\/\/)(?=(?<fqdn>[^:/]+))(?:(?<service>www|ww\d|cdn|ftp|mail|pop\d?|ns\d?|git)\.)?(?:(?<subdomain>[^:/]+)\.)*(?<domain>[^:/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)(?::(?<port>\d+))?(?<path>\/[^?]*)?(?:\?(?<query>[^#]*))?(?:#(?<hash>.*))?/i).groups)
```

output:

```
{
  "protocol": "https://",
  "fqdn": "www.sub.domain.google.com",
  "service": "www",
  "subdomain": "sub.domain",
  "domain": "google.com",
  "port": "443",
  "path": "/maps/place/Arc+De+Triomphe/@48.8737917,2.2928388,17z",
  "query": "query=1&foo",
  "hash": "hash"
}
```

So you can use whatever components you like

Comment: I would suggest adding a `?` around the first group so that it will not break when no protocol is present. But nice regex!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party but I want to answer the question with some extra useful info.

Get the domain name from a link using regex.

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\/]+)
```

Here is the link to [above regex](https://regex101.com/r/5ZopZv/1).

If you want to get the `subdomain`, `split` the result from one of the matches of above regex with the first occurrence of `.`

**Note:** `regex` is faster than language built-in modules. check below examples, `regex` comes out to be **15x** faster than the built-in module

javascript Example with Regex:

```
console.time('time2');
const pttrn = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\/]+)/gm
const urlInfo = pttrn.exec("https://www.google.co.in/imghp");
console.timeEnd('time2');

//time2: 0.055ms
console.log(urlInfo[0]) // https://www.google.co.in
console.log(urlInfo[1]) // https://
console.log(urlInfo[2]) // www.
console.log(urlInfo[3]) // google.co.in
```

Nodejs with built-in [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlparseurlstring-parsequerystring-slashesdenotehost) module

```
console.time('time');
const url = require('url');
const urlInfo = url.parse("https://www.google.co.in/imghp");
console.timeEnd('time');

//time: 0.840ms;
console.log(urlInfo.hostname) //www.google.co.in
```