# Clean and extract Subdomains & Domains from URLs using Regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, url, notepad++, subdomain

This is simple text file.

The URL:

- Can have https:// or http://
- Eliminate both as well as trailing url/ file paths
- Extract only domains and/or subdomains

I have Notepad++ and EditPlus

open to other Suggestions?

Examples:

> https://appspace.com
>
> http://appspace.com/
>
> http://ayurfit.ning.com/main/authorization/signIn
>
> http://bangalore.olx.in/login.php
>
> http://birthdayshoes.com/forum/index.php
>
> http://birthdayshoes.com/forum/register/
>
> http://forums.virtualbox.org/ucp.php

Tries:

```
/(?!.{253})((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.){1,126}+[A-Za-z]{2,6}/ 
^(?:https?://)?([^/.]+(?=\.)|)(\.?[^/.]+\.[^/]+)/?(.+|)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/hZ4cL4/4

Tried many on other machine as examples from Regex101

Found this little nugget as well. I'll post how its different once I understand it.

[Regular Expression - Extract subdomain & domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703360/regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain?rq=1)

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: Will do so. Its on another machine. Hold up. Copy pasting my tries.

Comment: /(?!.{253})((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.){1,126}+[A-Za-z]{2,6}/ - I think there should be a simpler way?

Comment: Did you try, say, `\b[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+\b`?

Comment: @stribizhev - Just did - It picks up the /index.php as well.

Comment: @stribizhev - What you posted is good. I just need to have it match the sub/domain after http/s:// and avoid the /.php etc

Comment: Like [`(?<=//)[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gT6lK1/1)?

Comment: It works almost perfect but hits this and splits it into two: `http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php`

Comment: Thats a fault in data - Your answer is right. Please post as Answer and i will give it credit @stribizhev

Comment: @AlexS: Posted as an answer since it proves helpful to you.

Comment: @stribizhev - Thank you. Just one thing. With the other one `^(?:https?://)?([^/.]+(?=\.)|)(\.?[^/.]+\.[^/]+)/?(.+|)$` I was able to do Find Replace using \1 \2. Here, I cant pull with \0, \1 or \2. What am I missing? Please add to answer so I can test and select yours finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the links that start with protocol, you can use the following regex:

```
(?<=://)[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB2bM9/1)

The `(?<=://)` look-behind makes sure there is `://` before the value we want to match, and the whole matched text consists of sequences of 1 or more word characters or hyphens (`[\w-]+`) that are eventually separated with periods.

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing. With the other one `^(?:https?://)?([^/.]+(?=\.)|)(\.?[^/.]+\.[^/]+)/?(.+|)$` I was able to do Find Replace using \1 \2. Here, I cant pull with \0, \1 or \2. What am I missing?

Comment: Check this one: [`^(?:https?://)?([^/.\n]+(?=\.))?(\.?[^/.\n]+\.[^/\n]+)/?(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kB2bM9/2). Replace with `\1\2` or `$1$2`.

Comment: Is there anything else you need to match in that document of yours? :)

Comment: I doubt it. Just testing it out today on several data logs. I think it should be a success. I will mark your answer as accepted once thats finished. I doubt there will be any more bugs. Thanks again. You will see a confirm from my end as soon as its over.

Comment: Found this little nugget as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703360/regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> You could simply extract anything that is between two `.` Additionally
>   you could use lookbehinds for http(s) and lookahead for the filepath
>   to fine tune your results.