# How To Combine These 2 Regexp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a Javascript routine that, given a hostname or a URL, it [finds the root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082426/105539).

```javascript
function getRootDomain(s){
  var sResult = ''
  try {
    sResult = s.match(/^(?:.*\:\/?\/)?(?<domain>[\w\-\.]*)/).groups.domain
      .match(/(?<root>[\w\-]*(\.\w{3,}|\.\w{2}|\.\w{2}\.\w{2}))$/).groups.root;
  } catch(ignore) {}
  return sResult;
}
```

What is the technique to combine the two regex rules into one rule?

I used [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) to try to advance my existing RegExp experience over the years, although I've never really understood lookbehinds and lookaheads (which might be useful here?), and then used the great tool at [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/) for trial and error. What I tried was to stick what's after `<root>` to replace what comes after `<domain>`, and variations on that, and all failed.

A test set to use with a tool like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) could be:

```
https://test.com:8080/?id=4&re=3
https://test-test.com:8080/?id=4&re=3
https://data.test.com:8080/?id=4&re=3
https://data.test.com/?id=4&re=3
https://data.test.com/
https://data.test.com#testing
https://data.test.com/#testing
https://data.test.com:8080/#testing
https://data.test.com:8080#testing
https://data.tester.com/
https://data-test.test.com/
https://test.com
https://test.com#testing
https://test.com/
https://test.am/?id=4
https://test.com?id=3&re=3
https://test.com/?id=3&re=3
https://megatest.com/?id=3&re=3

test.com
data.test.co.uk
test.co
data.test.com
data.tester-test.com
data-test.tester-test.com
tester-test.com
about:blank
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you're the one who posted the answer this was taken from. I thought it was someone else asking how to improve on your answer.

Comment: I saw your reputation when I was looking at the other answer. Like I said, I didn't notice that it was you posting this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second regexp uses the `$` assertion to only match the end of the `.domain` capture.

The first RegExp, however stops matching after the domain (when it meets either a `/`, a `?`, a `#`, a `:` or the end of the string if there is no path, query string or hash parts. So you can't just reuse the `$` assertion, it would fail in some cases.

To combine both parts, you could replace the `domain` capture with this:

`.*?(?<root>[\w\-]*(\.\w{3,}|\.\w{2}|\.\w{2}\.\w{2}))(?:[\/?#:]|$)`

`(?:[\/?#]|$)` at the end is a non-capturing group that matches either the target characters or the end of the string.

`.*?` frugally matches anything. That is, it first tries to match the `root` capture followed by `(?:[\/?#]|$)`. Every time that fails, it eats one character and tries again, letting you search for the `root`.

Also:

- you can combine `\.\w{3,}|\.\w{2}` into just `\.\w{2,}`.
- you can use a non-capturing group around the TLDs (`(?:...)` vs `(...)`.
- It would be better to use `.*?` to get the protocol, or you could end up globbing too much (with a greedy `.*`, passing https://example.com/#://bar.com would return `bar.com`).
- You don't need to escape the `:`. In unicode mode, that escape is actually a syntax error.

Resulting into

```
const x = /^(?:.*?:\/\/)?.*?(?<root>[\w\-]*(?:\.\w{2,}|\.\w{2}\.\w{2}))(?:[\/?#:]|$)/
```

I actually wrote a RegExp builder that may help you get further in your RegExp learning journey... [Here's your RegExp ported to `compose-regexp`](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4IWAA60ATsQAEwODACOAVybUYFOTAjFCMadqwYAngCMtczDgAmAYQwTiq6TDkY4c4hgDm2uFUwSAAPVjkwaVosOQAdGmipJQBaN18YEIl42LQcoTh5KNpiAFkMYmoDaTkAXjklNQ0YAAocuTkAegA9Doo2uRMLFo78ACoAfl64pA744zNLVpBZkABKVb60dpGJ3v6fXyWi4jm5ZH7t89iAd1jY5IBdUb2t9p09KtbXt7OAcnxftpZjdgAAmCisDoPTY-drIf6Azp3a5gyHaBHaJEg0GQh4XOSrfoPDb9XT6QzNDpXDrjADEiAeUw6ABIOoS0Oy8vQCnI3GBap0us1xogxiK7sCaatxmLhQAeY4APiut3uT2FiDu+GRYIhAB8tTqcYbsax1hrqXSGXrmatZrk0PlaLB8FBaIc+eynS63R7aMUyhUqqtKCAlLBqMQINy8ABORCg0FsDggGzcAjUOACBLCZg8NgPVhAA)

Comment: This works. You'll want to make a small revision to handle potential port numbers on the domains such as `https://data.test.com:8080/`. Here's the change I made: `/^(?:.*\:\/?\/)?.*?(?<root>[\w\-]*(\.\w{2,}|\.\w{2}\.\w{2}))(?:[\:\/?#]|$)/` I ran through regex101.com.

Comment: Great catch @Volomike, thanks! I've updated the answer accordingly. (And thanks to your upvote, I can at long last comment here, which is sweet :-)

Comment: @volomike, I've tweaked the response a bit with further refinements. Hopefully you'll find them helpful

Comment: In this part `^(?:.*?:\/\/?)?`, why the second-to-last `?` ? Shouldn't it be `^(?:.*?:\/\/)?` ? See, the `?` alone would mean "previous character is optional", when in fact all the characters there are optional -- one might see an https://, http://, ftp://, or perhaps just start with the domain.

Comment: It was present in your RegExp (applied to the first `/` I moved it to the second to put `':/`` in the same string), I thought you had a good reason to have it there...

Comment: I see. Yeah, that was my mistake. It was improved when you wrapped and added the `?` afterwards on the block (instead of individual characters) to mean "anything in there is optional".

Comment: I went ahead with my editing power and edited your answer to remove that extra ? that was unnecessary.