# BigQuery Domain Function Case Sensitivity Discrepancy

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

When using BigQuery query with Data containing URLs we noticed that the `DOMAIN` function behaves differently from the case of the URL.

This can be demonstrated with this simple query:

```
SELECT
    domain('WWW.FOO.COM.AU'),
    domain(LOWER('http://WWW.FOO.COM.AU/')),
    domain('http://WWW.FOO.COM.AU/')
```

The result of URL of full uppercase does not seem to be right and the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#domain) does not mentioned anything regarding case in URLs.

[image: Query Result]

Comment: i feel like this is a bug while detecting original top-level domains like .com .net .org etc. - looks like they are lower-cased. the rest doesn't matter and is carried as is. thus same issue with TLD()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMAIN` (and the other URL-handling functions in legacy SQL) have a number of limitations, unfortunately. While we don't have an equivalent yet in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under Options), you can make up your own that works in more cases using a regular expression. There are [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex) of [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703360/regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain) about domain extraction, and we can put one of the answers to use as:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION GetDomain(url STRING) AS (
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)'));

WITH T AS (
  SELECT url
  FROM UNNEST(['WWW.FOO.COM.AU:8080', 'google.com',
               'www.abc.xyz', 'http://example.com']) AS url)
SELECT
  url,
  GetDomain(url) AS domain
FROM T;

+---------------------+----------------+
|         url         |     domain     |
+---------------------+----------------+
| www.abc.xyz         | abc.xyz        |
| WWW.FOO.COM.AU:8080 | WWW.FOO.COM.AU |
| google.com          | google.com     |
| http://example.com  | example.com    |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Parsing URL in regex is fine, and most of the time I could just get away with it by lower-casing the URL before applying the function. This's not a deal breaker anyway,it's just I hope that this could be documented somewhere in the manual.

Comment: That's a good suggestion; I filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=638. Thanks!