# javascript regex or string method to only match subdomain and domain (minus top levels)

Tags: javascript, regex

In a browser I want to figure out what the subdomain and domain name for the page I am on is, minus the top levels like 'com' and '.co.uk'.

Also, if the subdomain is 'www' I don't want a match on that.

Examples:

```
https://www.voice-1.mozilla.co.uk/folder/index.html
https://www.voice-1.mozilla.org.uk/folder/index.html
http://www.voice-1.mozilla.com/folder/index.html
http://www.voice-1.mozilla.com:8080/folder/index.html
```

will all have the matches `voice-1` and `mozilla`

It would be nice to not have to maintain top level domains, but maintaining different variations of `www` is okay.

So far I've gotten to skip `com` and `co.uk` but not `www` or `org.uk` and not anything else before a `.` in the file path: [regex-test](https://regex101.com/r/22ThY6/5)

The regex is now:

```
/[\w\-]{3,}(?=[.])/g
```

How to go about to achieve this?

**Edit:**
Having a step after the regex, trimming away unwanted `www`, `co` in `co.uk` and `org` in `org.uk` is okay. But I still need to get the top level removed and anything else before a `.` in the file-path. Basically grabbing everything between `//` and first `/`, except top level domain.

Comment: What happens when you have a `.org.uk` domain? `.org` gets matched too, this way

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703360/regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain

Comment: @jeremy-thille: Looked at that one earlier. I want one match for `voice-1` and one for `mozilla` So not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, @aaron. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you @luca-kiebel, That is something I want removed too, but not fully sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get [this](https://regex101.com/r/v1jsTA/1). Got rid of `www` and `index`.

```
\.([\w\-]{3,})(?=[\.])
```

If string methods are allowed, you can try something like this.

```
str = 'https://www.voice-1.mozilla.co.uk/folder/index.html'
arr = str.split('/')
result = arr[2].split('.')
```

You will get every part separately in `result`. You need to check first element (is it `www` or not), same for last two elements (check length and content). I don't think there is any pattern you can use here.

Comment: But then I get `.voice-1` and `.mozilla` as matches.

Comment: This doesn't only get rid of `www`, it gets rid of the lowest domain level whatever it is, which might be a problem.

Comment: @EspenKlem you get `voice` and `mozilla` as groups.

Comment: True @EganWolf, but then you have the issue Aaron pointed out

Comment: Thanks, @EganWolf! I'll go with the string methods.