# flutter compare check if two urls are similar

Tags: flutter, url

I would like to compare two url links in flutter and see if they are similar then return a true value. An example is comparing the below links

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Comment: you can simply compare Strings "https://stackoverflow.com/" == "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" ? doThis() : doThat()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```dart
var link1 = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
var link2 = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

print(link2.contains(link1)); => it will return true
```

Answer (score 0):

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703406/9977583) shows regex for domain name matching.
You can use it like this:

```
  final domainRegex = RegExp(r"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)");

  var firstUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
  var secondUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

  var firstDomain = domainRegex.firstMatch(first_url)?.group(1);   //stackoverflow.com
  var secondDomain = domainRegex.firstMatch(second_url)?.group(1);   //stackoverflow.com

  print(firstDomain == secondDomain);  //returns true
```